# use ajax v1.11.1 for form submitting with a image file upload to database jsp servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I use this code for image upload to a database but it is not success. it doesn't pass the data from jsp to servlet and the console show the code error code of **Illegal invocation** please help me to solve this problem the code segments are showing in below

**error code:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
       at e (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
       at Vc (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
       at Vc (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
       at Function.m.param (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
       at Function.ajax (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
       at HTMLInputElement.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2), <anonymous>:95:36)
       at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3)
       at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3)
```

**1.This is my Form.**

```
<form id="formAddEmployee" name="formAddEmployee" method="post" action="" autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

<td class="page_input_td">
                        <input  accept="image/*"  type="file" name="signature" id="signature" >
                    </td>
```

**2.My Script file**

```
var formData = new FormData();
                if ($('#signature').length !== 0) {
                    formData.append('signature', $('#signature')[0].files[0]);
                }


var submitData = $.ajax({
                    url: "${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/AddEmployeeServlet",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {"employeeId": employeeId,
                        "name": name,
                        "nic": nic,
                        "contactNo": contactNo,
                        "email": email,
                        "address": address,
                        "designation": designation,
                        "department": department,
                        "formData": formData,
                        "formData": formData,
                        "status": status},
                    async: true,
                    cache: false
                });
```